# KIvy using a circles position to place a button

Tags: python, button, kivy

I have drawn a circle. I want to place a button at the same position of the circle. How can I get the circle's x and y coordinates. My code(in kv file):

```
MainWidget:


<MainWidget>:
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 0, 0
        Ellipse:
            id: point
            size: 100, 100
            pos: 100, root.y1

    Button:
        id: No1
        pos: point.pos
        on_press: root.move()
```

It shows "NameError: name 'point' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Put your widgets in `BoxLayout`. You can't use **id** for `canvas`, you should use [groups](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.InstructionGroup).

**Circle above the button.**

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App


KV = '''
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 10
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x: None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 0, 0
                Ellipse:
                    size: 100, 100
                    pos: self.pos
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                id: No1
                on_press: pass
'''


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```

**Circle in the button.**

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

KV = '''
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 50
        Button:
            on_press: pass
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 0, 0
                Ellipse:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
'''


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```

So you can place the circle at the same position as the button.

```py
Ellipse:
    size: 100, 100
    pos: self.pos
```

Comment: I want to get the position of the circle from the canvas. So that I can use it Later.

Comment: This is very easy to do, set the `id` of the `BoxLayout`, then the position of the circle will be - `self. root.ids.canvas_layout.pos`. I see you've changed your question)